# What is the "Smart Battery Connector" for 9V rechargeable batteries?

Tags: power, battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, bms, smbus

I'm looking for a battery charger for 9V rechargeable batteries (must be switch-mode, not linear).

I came across the "Smart Battery Standard Connector" structure in a controller IC datasheet (MAX1647 battery charger controller) I was reviewing. This connector consists of 5 pins (B+, B-, Thermal, SCL, SDA).

A 9V rechargeable battery has 2 pins as standard (B+, B-).

How can I use this connector on a 9V battery? Do I need to use bms circuit for thermal and SMbus pins (SCL and SDA)?

Comment: Have you read the datasheet? It is a generic charge controller IC. You need to tell it how to charge the batteries over the SMBus (which is pretty much a standard two wire interface/I2C etc but with Intel's logo on it). And the thermal is a standard saftey temperture monitoring feature. You don't need a BMS, you need to talk to the IC with something such as a uC or uP to set the MAX1647 up. If you are looking for a specific battery chemisty and set up, look for an IC which is designed for that. But finding such a device is a shopping question and so not in the scope of this site.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I have read the datasheet. There is "smart battery standard connector" in the schematic design on page 9. Of course, the controller IC will determine how to charge the battery by communicating with the processor. What I don't understand here is: How do I get the thermal and scl-sda pins from the battery? Here is what I understand:

1) Smart battery is a different type of battery (i.e. different from known standard 2-pin (B+, B-) batteries).

2) Therefore, I cannot use 9V or 18650 Li-Ion or AA size NiMH batteries in this project.

Are these inferences correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a smart battery, you can e.g. use the variant MAX1648, where you configure the chemistry, voltage and current by hardware.

The smart battery interface can be considered as a kind of electronic datasheet inside a battery to be read by chargers. And some life, cycle and error data can be read as well.

This is similar to the way a PC reads the capabilities of a connected monitor, also using I2C bus hardware.